# using cefsharp with fody

Tags: c#, cefsharp, fody-costura

I am using fody costura to combine all my files into a single executable.
in my project I am using cefsharp and it is looking for locales folder with en-US.pak file.

I am getting the following error:

```
[0114/060326.954:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(358)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
[0114/060326.955:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(714)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
```

fody is looking for the file in the following folder

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Costura\60B52F2D9303A2A6B945E41F3A43E7AC\32\locales\en-US.pak
```

Should I just create locales folder and copy en-US.pak there from embedded resource?

what is the correct way to add locales\en-US.pak file?

Comment: unpack it to some temp directory and then use LocalesDirPath ... there is no automatic way

Comment: thank you for a quick reply, what I tried is adding en-US.pak to fody as embeded resource and copy and then setting CefSettings LocalesDirPath to "." but still did not work.

Comment: Selvin, i checked and just realized I was extracting the resource after the call to Cef.Initialized and that is why i was getting this error. Thank you.   Now I am on the next problem ;~(

Failed to launch GPU process

any suggestions?

Comment: i moved the question to a different thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189124/using-fody-costura-in-a-project-with-cefsharp